# A team member made a mistake and I need to manage it

Tags: management, communication, team

One of my team member made a mistake and a manager noticed it who sent me an email regarding a follow up meeting with the team member. However my concern here is that the mistake was witnessed by one of my senior manager who I have a healthy positive relationship with which I would like to maintain.

Should I reply his email and how should I respond?

The correct action has already been taken by the manager. I just need to reply that I will provide One-On-One counselling with the team member to ensure that they do not repeat this mistake again.

Comment: because the manager wrote me an email about it.

Comment: @keshlam, if you think the question isn't a good fit, click the 'flag' button under the question and select 'this should be closed for another reason' followed by 'unclear what you're asking' and it will be reviewed by the community. That will have more effect than making a comment. If you do leave a comment, it's most helpful if you explain to the person asking how they can make an [edit] to fix it by asking clarification questions, etc. (This is not an obligation, just nice). Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the nature of the email you want to reply to?

Comment: its about telling the manager , that i have councel my team member and advised him to have accurate information release and be confirmed of what to be done

Comment: Does the team member who made the mistake work under you, or alongside you? If he doesn't report to you, why are you responsible for "counseling" him?

Comment: he works under me

Comment: I think my answer would depend on the nature of the mistake. If it's a simple technical matter, easily corrected, that goes under the category of "it happens, we'll take care of it." If it was something that isn't easily corrected, that's a very different kettle of worms.

Answer (score 4):

The manager cares that the mistake be fixed.

Reply to the manager that you are on the case, that fixing the mistake should take x hours and that you'll send him a message once you've verified that the team member fixes that mistake. If fixing the mistake takes say a day, send your manager periodic reports that the team member is fixing the mistake and that the repair process is on track schedule-wise. Once you've verified that the team member has made the requisite fix, report to the manager that the mistake is officially fixed and if there is anything else that the manager needs or wants, then the manager please let you know about it.That's all there is to the process.